# How to serve react build with express.js from elastic beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been having some trouble getting elastic beanstalk to serve React from Node.js.. What I have been doing so far works locally, but I cannot seem to find a way to set a path in elastic beanstalk in order for it to serve react.

I have an express app.js file on the root directory, and react inside a "client" folder from the root directory. And this is my express app.js code:

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path"
import morgan from "morgan"

const app = express();
const __dirname = path.resolve();

/* ---------- App Use ---------- */
app.use(morgan('tiny'))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});
/* ---------- App Use ---------- */

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('just gonna send it');
});

let PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000
app.listen(PORT, function() {
 console.log("Server started successfully on: " + PORT);
});
```

When I run npm start, the react build serves normally, but on elastic beanstalk it just prints 'just gonna send it' and nothing. Is this a path issue? If so how could I solve this with elastic beanstalk settings? I would really appreciate some feedback and solutions on this.. thank you so much.

Comment: Elastic beanstalk is better used for docker

Comment: I am adamant on using elastic beanstalk sir. But curious, which other aws products would work better?

Comment: For react s3 , ec2 for backend.

Answer (score 0):

managed to make it work. It was an .ebextensions tweak alongside some node js setup as well as working with react production build. I have made a boilerplate for it if anyone needs it in the future:

https://github.com/brianlee1597/elastic_beanstalk-MERN-Boilerplate

^ above has react-node-express. No DB.

Comment: The repo is gone